# SWT Table column offset/padding

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT `Table` with multiple columns. In this example, let's say there are three columns. The cells of each column all contain an image followed by some text (example pictured below). However, as you can see there is no spacing between the 2 - 3 column lines and their cells.

Is there a built-in way to add a buffer zone to those cells so the icons don't appear right on the edge line? Such as an offset property of some kind? I don't see any property overtly listed in either `Table` or `TableColumn`.

If not, is there a workaround beyond just adding white space to the cell images?

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to make my question clearer.

Table:

[image: table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a designated way to adjust the margin and spacing of image and text within a cell. Apart from adding transparent pixels to the image (as you already suggested), you can use a `PaintListener` to gain control over how a cell is rendered.

The example below draws image and text with adjustable margin and spacing:

```
Listener paintListener = new Listener() {
  int leftMargin = 40;
  int rightMargin = 10;
  int imageSpacing = 200;
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    TableItem item = ( TableItem )event.item;
    Rectangle imageBounds = image.getBounds();
    Point textExtent = event.gc.textExtent( item.getText() );
    switch( event.type ) {
      case SWT.MeasureItem: {
        event.width += leftMargin + imageBounds.width + imageSpacing + textExtent.x + rightMargin;
        event.height = Math.max( event.height, imageBounds.height + 2 );
        event.height = Math.max( event.height, textExtent.y + 2 );
        break;
      }
      case SWT.PaintItem: {
        int x = event.x + leftMargin;
        int imageOffset = ( event.height - imageBounds.height ) / 2;
        event.gc.drawImage( image, x, event.y + imageOffset );
        x += imageSpacing;
        int textOffset = ( event.height - textExtent.y ) / 2;
        event.gc.drawText( item.getText(), x, event.y + textOffset );
        break;
      }
      case SWT.EraseItem: {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
      }
    }
  }
};
table.addListener( SWT.MeasureItem, paintListener );
table.addListener( SWT.PaintItem, paintListener );
table.addListener( SWT.EraseItem, paintListener );
```

For a more thorough understanding of owner-drawn items in SWT please read the [Custom Drawing Table and Tree Items](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) article.

If you are using a JFace `TableViewer`, there is also an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` as shown in this example:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#styledcelllabelprovider-and-ownerdrawlabelprovider

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using a JFace TableViewer, and design specifications prevent me from placing the images at the right side of the cell. It looks like my best option is to insert transparent pixels at the left of the image. I've been looking into a way to do this with GC without creating extra handles (some examples show using a temporary transparent image). Do you by chance know of a way or have a link to a good issue?

Comment: You don't need to use JFace, a plain `PaintListener` will also do. The linked SWT Snippet is just an example that you could use as a starting point to learn how to position an image.